# Set dropdown value using angular js

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to set the dropdown value on basis of json result returned by mvc controller.

Code behind (mvc controller)

```
 public ActionResult GetProject(int Id)
        {
            using (ManagementSystemEntities db = new ManagementSystemEntities())
            {
                return Json(db.SelectProject(Id).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Above lines are working correctly. It returns list of projects.

List returned :

```
Id    Title
1      test
2      test2
```

I want to select dropdown value as "test" by its value which is Id = 1

HTML >>

```
 <select ng-options="project.Title for project in projectList" id="ddlProject" ng-model="selectedProject">
      <option value="">-- Select Project --</option>
      <option data-ng-repeat="project in projectList" value="{{project.Id}}"> {{project.Title}}</option>
    </select>
```

There is no issue which is related to angular loading. Everything working fine. Only need is to set the dropdown value on basis of ajax result.

Ajax Call (angular code) >>

Code for Populating dropdown options : (Working fine)

```
$http.get(service_url + "Project/GetProject", { params: { "id": 0 } })
           .success(function (response) {
                if (response.length < 1) {
                    // No Record

                }
                else {

                    $scope.projectlist = response;
                }
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                fnsuccessmodal("error in load", "error");
            });
```

Code for set value in dropdown :

```
$http.get(service_url + "Project/GetProject", { params: { "Id": 1 } })
           .success(function (response) {
               if (response.length < 1) {
                   // No Record
               }
               else {
                    $.each(response, function (index, item) {

                       //console.log(item.ProjectId);  it is displaying 1 as in console screen I am only getting project which have Id equal to 1.

                       $scope.selectedProject = $scope.projectList[item.ProjectId]; // This line not working

                   });
               }
           })
         .error(function (data) {
             fnSuccessModal("Error in Load", "Error");
         });
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you try this? `<select ng-options="project as project.Title for project in projectList track by Id" id="ddlProject" ng-model="selectedProject"><option value="">-- Select Project --</option></select>` or do you have another reason to have ng-options and ng-repeat on same select element? And why are you setting the selected value to each element of the projectList?

Comment: Can you give an exemple o the list returned by "Project/GetProject" then Id = 0 and  Id = 1

Comment: @JoseRocha thanks for your time and help... I have edited the question. please see the example of the list returned.

Comment: If the list have as parameter Id and Title from where did it comes the ProjectId in the response, when id = 1? Another thing is that you are bubbling some problems that you will not see it right now, but it will blow in some time.

Comment: @JoseRocha it was just a typo.. actually it is Id , not ProjectId. It should be [item.Id] Please let me know which problem you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some recomendations. If you don´t want them go to the (BUT) bellow. First you should return a list if you going to pass a collection, and just one item if you want to search by id and the id is the primary key of the project.
I have write this here so there are possible some errors.

```
public ActionResult GetProject(int? Id)
{
    using (ManagementSystemEntities db = new ManagementSystemEntities())
    {
        return Json( id.HasValue ? db.SelectProject(Id).FirstOrDefault() : db.SelectAllProjects().ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

this way to get the list you can change your code to

```
$http.get(service_url + "Project/GetProject", { })
       .success(function (response) {
            if (response.length < 1) {
                // No Record
            }
            else {
                $scope.projectlist = response;
            }
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            fnsuccessmodal("error in load", "error");
        });
```

to get the selected project, by your logic

```
$http.get(service_url + "Project/GetProject", { params: { "Id": 1 } })
       .success(function (response) {
           if (response) {
                   $scope.selectedProject = response; 
               });
           }
       })
     .error(function (data) {
         fnSuccessModal("Error in Load", "Error");
     });
```

for the markup, you should not have an an ng-options inside ng-repeat

```
<select ng-options="project as project.Title for project in projectList track by project.Id" id="ddlProject" ng-model="selectedProject">
  <option value="">-- Select Project --</option>
</select>
```

**BUT** if you don´t want to change the things that i talked about just change this and it shoul work. It´s your choice

```
$http.get(service_url + "Project/GetProject", { params: { "Id": 1 } })
       .success(function (response) {
           if (response.length < 1) {
               // No Record
           }
           else {
                $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                   //console.log(item.ProjectId);  it is displaying 1 as in console screen I am only getting project which have Id equal to 1.

                   $scope.selectedProject = item:
               });
           }
       })
     .error(function (data) {
         fnSuccessModal("Error in Load", "Error");
     });
```

and the markup you have to introduce a track by so

```
<select ng-options="project as project.Title for project in projectList track by project.Id" id="ddlProject" 
ng-model="selectedProject">
  <option value="">-- Select Project --</option>
</select>
```

here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/z317TLUNIuONS66ft0LA?p=preview) that i created with my opinion where the http.get where replaced by timeouts

here you can find documentation for [ngRepeat track by](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Best,

Comment: Thanks .. I just need to change as , $scope.selectedProject = { Id: item.ProjectId, Title: item.Project }; .... and it worked. !!! :-)